# page.evaluate() Как Передать несколько параметров в функцию?)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Получаю вот такую ошибку при использовании этой функции

> Error: Too many arguments. If you need to pass more than 1 argument to the function wrap them in an object

```js
  async waitForValue(page, selector, value) {
    const result = await page.evaluate(
      (selector, value) =>
        document.querySelector(selector).getAttribute('value').includes(value),
      selector,
      value,
    )
    console.log(result)
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Внезапно, нужно просто передать несколько аргументов.

Чуть-чуть изменённый пример из [документации](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    // (x, y, z) - приняли три аргумента
    const result = await page.evaluate((x, y, z) => {
        return Promise.resolve(x * y * z);
    // 7, 8, 9 - передали три аргумента
    }, 7, 8, 9);
    console.log(result);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Что касается предстваленного вами кода, то он наводит на предположение о том, что присутсвует [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy), т.к. он отвечает на вопрос из заголовка. Но если на странице не окажется элемента подходяшего под передаваемый селектор, то `document.querySelector(selector)` вернёт `null` что в даст ошибку, т.к. `null` не имеет метода `getAttribute`.

Если передавать одним аргументом, как предлагается в ошибке:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    // Теперь всё внутри args
    const result = await page.evaluate((args) => {
        return Promise.resolve(args.x * args.y * args.z);
    
    // Передали объектом
    }, {x:7, y:8, z:9});
    console.log(result);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Спасибо,да не совсем корректно задал вопрос.Добавил ошибку в описание."Error: Too many arguments. If you need to pass more than 1 argument to the function wrap them in an object"

Comment: В таком случае, есть смысл сделать так, как говорится в ошибке - передать рагументы объетом. Я правильно понимаю что работа идёт не именно с puppeteer, а с Pa11y?

Comment: Спасибо,не понимал как правильно передавать.Я использую Playwrigth